# 2015 Community Moderator Election Results

Tags: discussion, election

Personal Finance & Money's [2 moderator election](https://money.stackexchange.com/election/2) has come to a close, the votes have been tallied, and the 2 new moderators are:

[image: Alex B] [image: Ganesh Sittampalam]

Please thank them for volunteering, and share your assistance and advice with them as they learn the ropes!

For details on how the voting played out, you can download the election results [here](https://money.stackexchange.com/election/2), or [view a summary report online](http://www.opavote.org/results/4834850506801152/0).

Comment: Thanks all! I'm glad to join the mod team again. :)

Comment: All hail our new mods! Congrats on the new jobs, thanks for the work. Double pay for everyone!

Comment: Congratulations to you both, Alex and Ganesh!

Comment: Congratulations to both of you!

Comment: Thanks all! I'm looking forward to helping out.

Comment: Congratulations Alex and Ganesh, thanks for volunteering to take this up.